# Type conversion in EXEC statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

Imagine that we have following declaration:

```
declare @a int;
set @a = 1;
```

And there is a need to generate some informational message, such as:

```
select 'the value of @a is ' + @a;
```

The above statement will generate error, because of type conversion is required, and the right way to do it is:

```
select 'the value of @a is ' + convert(varchar(10), @a);
```

Then, if the same thing need to be done dynamically, one may expect that the following should be correct:

```
exec('select ''the value of @a is ' + convert(varchar(10), @a) + '''');
```

Surprisingly it is not, and generates syntax error. In opposite to `select` statement, the right way to do it in this case is:

```
exec('select ''the value of @a is ' + @a + '''');
```

So the question is, why type conversion is required in the `select` statement, but illegal in the `exec(string)` statement?

Answer (score 0):

syntax has been checked while we run any **DML statement**. As we know Exec is not a DML statement its give the SQL Enviornment to run any Script.
exec( 'select ''the value of @a is ' + @a + '''') in exec doing implicit conversion.
in this case.
exec('select ''the value of @a is ' + convert(varchar(10), @a) + ''''); 
you are using convert function this is used in DML operation and its checking the syntax before exec.

```
declare @a int,@str varchar(8000)=''
set @a = 124586;

select @str='select ''the value of @a is ' + convert(varchar(10), @a) + ''''
exec( 'select ''the value of @a is ' + @a + '''')
exec(@str);
```