# Concatenating INT and VARCHAR inside EXEC not producing conversion error

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

Given the following table:

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE #T(Val INT);
INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
```

I wanted to execute a dynamic sql query using `EXEC` given a `Val` value:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Val INT = 3;

EXEC ('SELECT * FROM #T WHERE Val = ' + @Val);
```

This executes without error and gives the correct result.

My assumption is that this will produce an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT * FROM #T
>   WHERE Val = ' to data type int.

Since `@Val` is of `INT` data type and by the rules of the [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), the query inside the `EXEC` must be converted to `INT`.

My question is why didn't the call to `EXEC` produce a conversion error?

---

*Notes:*

*- I know about `sp_executesql`. I'm not also asking for an alternative. I'm just asking for an explanation why no error was produced.*

*- The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2646492/2203084) does not seem to explain my situation as the question refers to `VARCHAR` to `VARCHAR` concatenation.*

Comment: I *believe* that this is a holdover from the bad-old-days. Even back on e.g. SQL Server 2000, you could `EXEC` with multiple strings `+`ed together that would have exceeded the 8000/4000 character limits for varchar/nvarchar at the time. Therefore, I believe that the `+` inside an `EXEC()` is *not* the standard string concatenation operator. Although the function is only specified to accept string data types, I'd guess that means it's going to stringify any non-string types and data precedence can go walk off a short pier. But this is just speculation, hence not an answer.

Comment: A similar question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135174/type-conversion-in-exec-statement

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, you have a very interesting theory, one observation though: the following does not work: EXEC( 'SELECT ' + 3 ) but concatenation with am `INT` variable works.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've read that about the character limit in Erland's article. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Alex - yes, agreed. Worth noting though that that fails during compilation (syntax error) whereas the conversion error is a runtime error.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I believe the real answer is a combination of your theory and Andrew Morton's point about implicit conversion: try the experiment with a variable of type `XML`, result: "Implicit conversion from data type xml to nvarchar is not allowed."

Comment: @Alex - and we can demonstrate that the `+` within `EXEC` is only working with string types with `declare @i int;declare @j int;select @i=1,@j=2;exec (@i+@j)` which produces "Incorrect syntax near '12'", so the original data types definitely don't matter.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I saw this as well. I am guessing that all types are implicitly converted to string (`NVARCHAR`). It fails if no imlpicit conversion is allowed (see XML comment above). And if you specify a constant then compilation fails i.e. EXEC is not even executed.

Comment: @Alex I thought so too. As Damien pointed out earlier, all variables are converted implicitly to `(N)VARCHAR`. And since `INT` can be converted to `(N)VARCHAR`, there is no error produced. Unlike with the `XML` data type. If only there's a documentation somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps there is a clue in the MSDN article for EXEC() which states that [N] 'tsql_string' Is a constant string. tsql_string can be any nvarchar or varchar data type. If the N is included, the string is interpreted as nvarchar data type. Perhaps a constant string is treated differently to a variable string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [MSDN/BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx), simplified syntax for `EXEC[UTE]` statement is:

```
Execute a character string  
{ EXEC | EXECUTE }   
    ( { @string_variable | [ N ]'tsql_string' } [ + ...n ] )  
    [ AS {  USER } = ' name ' ]  
[;] 

@string_variable
Is the name of a local variable. @string_variable can be any char, varchar, nchar, or nvarchar data type. These include the (max) data types.
```

Few notes:

1) According to this line `( { @string_variable | [ N ] 'command_string [ ? ]' } [ **+** ...n ]`, we can write something like this `EXEC (@var1 + @var2 + @var3)` but according to last paragraph SQL Server expects these variables to be/have one of following *string* data type: `char`, `varchar`, `nchar`, or `nvarchar`.

2) Also, this syntax references only `string variables` (`@string_variable | [ N ] 'command_string [ ? ]' } [ + ...n`). I believe that this is the reason why `EXEC ('SELECT * FROM #T WHERE Val = ' + 3);` fails: `3` isn't a variable.

3) I assume that **when** one of these variables don't have one of above string types then SQL Server will do an implicit conversion. I assume it will convert from source variable from `INT` (for example) to `NVARCHAR` because it has the highest [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/library/ms190309.aspx) between these string types.

4) This is not the only place where [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/library/ms190309.aspx) doesn't work. `ISNULL(param1, param2)` it's just another example. In this case, `param2` will be converted to data type of `param1`.

Comment: Yep, the thing after the `+` is only allowed to be a string in the grammar so will be interpreted as a string before the concatenation. The acceptance of variables that aren't in fact any of `char`, `varchar`, `nchar`, or `nvarchar` doesn't seem to be documented though so probably should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

An implicit conversion from `int` to string types is allowed, at least as far back as SQL Server 2008.

Ref: [Data Type Conversion (Database Engine)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx)

You cannot disable the implicit conversion: [Is there a way to turn off implicit type conversion in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7605297/1115360)

Edit: I originally wrote

> `'SELECT * FROM #T WHERE Val = ' + @Val` is created before the call to `EXEC`.

I am not so sure about that. I now suspect that the argument to `EXEC` is passed to part of the DB engine that parses it in a different way to what we are used to seeing.

Comment: The issue isn't implicit conversion but priority. `int` has priority so   `select 'SELECT * FROM #T WHERE Val = ' + @Val` throws a varchar to int conversion error. EXEC though behaves differently

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Nevertheless, it must be what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

All that MSDN tell about concatinating in EXEC[UTE] is:

> the concatenation is performed logically in the SQL Server parser and never materializes in memory.

So we can not know much about what does SQL Server deep inside. All we know is that EXEC does not accept an expression as an argument, instead it accepts a list of strings delimited by '+'.

If you look at the syntax:

```
Execute a character string  
{ EXEC | EXECUTE }   
    ( { @string_variable | [ N ]'tsql_string' } [ + ...n ] )  
    [ AS { LOGIN | USER } = ' name ' ]  
[;]
```

It directly supports a number of strings or variables separated by '+' character. So you are not actually passing an expression to EXEC, and so you are bypassing the SQL Server expression parser.

Comment: But why didn't the concatenation of `int` and `varchar` produce an error?